# class com.bea.alsb.tools.configjar.ant.ConfigJarTask cannot be found

Tags: java, maven, ant, soa, osb

We are trying to invoke ant using maven in an osb project

And we are getting the below error

taskdef class com.bea.alsb.tools.configjar.ant.ConfigJarTask cannot be found

================= Below is build XML

```
<property environment="env" /> 
<property name="mw.home" location="${env.MW_HOME}"/> 
<property name="wl.home" location="${env.WL_HOME}"/> 
<property name="osb.home" location="${env.OSB_HOME}"/> 
            <property name="settingsFile" location="D:\osb_ant\settings.xml"/> 


<taskdef name="configjar" 
         classname="com.bea.alsb.tools.configjar.ant.ConfigJarTask"/> 

<target name="init">
   <property name="task.debug" value="false" /> 
   <property name="task.failonerror" value="true" /> 
   <property name="task.errorproperty" value="" /> 

</target>

<target name="run" depends="init">

   <fail unless="settingsFile"/>

   <configjar debug="${task.debug}" 
              failonerror="${task.failonerror}" 
              errorProperty="${task.errorproperty}" 
              settingsFile="${settingsFile}" />
</target>
```

Comment: Make sure setenv is run before, and also check your classpath.  It sounds like config.jar is not in it.

Answer (score 2):

You have specified mw.home, wl.home and osb.home based on environment variables MW_HOME, WL_HOME and OSB_HOME. Are those actually set?

try calling $WL_HOME/server/bin/setWLSEnv.sh (or equivalent) before running ant.